# Return records that don't have specific key - Rails4 HStore Postgresql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.1, hstore

I have a model Task

```
t.string   "name"
t.hstore   "actions"
```

Example:

```
#<Task id: 1, name: "first", actions: {"today"=>"9"}, 
#<Task id: 2, name: "second", actions: {"yesterday"=>"1"}, 
#<Task id: 3, name: "third", actions: nil,
#<Task id: 4, name: "four", actions: {"today"=>"11"},
```

I need to find all records where actions: nil, :today<10 and key :today not present.
It is 1,2,3 task.

```
Task.where("actions -> 'today' < '10'") - it return only first task.
Task.where("actions -> 'today' < '10' OR actions IS NULL")  - it return 1 and 3 records.
```

How i can find all records which do not have the key :today in action?

Comment: Do you mean you want Tasks 2,3 in return and not 1,2,3 tasks?  I see today is present in Task 1.

Comment: I need return 1,2,3 Tasks.

Comment: Does anything exist in your actions like 'day before yesterday'?  What are the possibilities, just `today` and `yesterday` or are there more?

Comment: More. Task.where("actions -> 'today' < '10' OR actions IS NULL") - this return 1 and 3 record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/06/mastering-the-postgresql-hstore-date-type/), according to your question:

```
Task.where("actions IS NULL OR EXIST(actions, 'today') = FALSE")
```

and according to your comments:

```
Task.where("actions -> 'today' < '10' OR actions IS NULL OR EXIST(actions, 'today') = FALSE")
```

Comment: Brilliant answer just what was reqd. ty!