# Rails - find all records where an hstore key is either not present or = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hstore

How does one find all objects in a class where an hstore key is either not present or, if present, not nil?

Products table has an hstore for `:image_urls`

```
t.hstore   "image_urls", default: {}
```

This will get all Products where no useful value has been set for `image_urls`:

```
Product.where(image_urls: ['', nil])
```

However what if I want to find all the Products where Products `image_urls[:thumbnail]` is either nil or nonexistent?

This doesn't work:

```
Product.where(image_urls[:thumbnail]: ['', nil])
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to look at PostgreSQL docs for this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE

Comment: Thanks! that led me to a solution. If you want to post answer below I'll give you credit:  `Product.where("image_urls @> 'thumbnail=NULL'")`

Comment: still want to find both key missing OR key = NULL. Can you combine ActiveRecord query with SQL?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help with the key missing or NULL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17646122/511203

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following operators:

```
hstore ? key     # does hstore contain key?
hstore @> hstore # does left hstore contain right?
```

So the final solution would be:

```
Product.where("not image_urls ? 'thumbnail' or not image_urls @> 'thumbnail=>NULL'")
```